Cypress - Stringing data-test id together using commands.js fails but when stringing them together not using the command works
Hope someone can make sense of this
I have created commands for search on data id's
Cypress.Commands.add('getByDataQAId', (selector, ...args) => {
    return cy.get(`[data-qa-id=${selector}]`, ...args)
})

Cypress.Commands.add('findByDataQAId', (selector, ...args) => {
    return cy.find(`[data-qa-id=${selector}]`, ...args)
})

I am now using these to search for an element on the screen, Due to how the screen is layed out and how the dev's have created the id's I need to use these together
cy.getByDataQAId('card-detail').filter(':visible').findByDataQAId('sub-title'),

When calling this cypress fails on the Find part saying "the subject received was "undefined""
When calling this below (which for me is the same)
cy.get('[data-qa-id="card-detail"]').filter(':visible').find('[data-qa-id="sub-title"]')

This finds the field correctly. So now I am confused on why the first fails while the second passes.
Thanks for your time

I think Nak is nearly right, but you also need to designate the custom command as a child command.
This is indicated by the option {prevSubject:true}.
Cypress.Commands.add('findByDataQAId', {prevSubject:true}, (subject, selector, ...args) => {
  return cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-qa-id=${selector}]`, ...args)
})

There's examples of child command here.

The prevSubject accepts the following values:

false: (default) ignore any previous subjects: (parent command)
true: receives the previous subject: (child command)
optional: may start a chain, or use an existing chain: (dual command)



I think it is losing the reference to the first subject at the time of the second call because you are not wrapping that.
You could add something like:
Cypress.Commands.add('getByDataQAId', (subject, tag) => {
   return subject
   ? cy.wrap(subject).find(`[data-qa-id='${tag}']`)
   : cy.get(`[data-qa-id='${tag}']`)
})

